# betweenness with python-igraph and networkx

Tags: python-2.7, networkx, igraph

I have a large graph with 250,000 nodes and 1 million edges to calculate its vertice betweenness (without any weight). I aim to use python-igraph to complete this work because it supports parallel computation with some other packages. When I compare the results from python-igarph and networkx on a relative small latttice with 100 vertices (see the figure). I find they are completely different. Even for a lattice with 9 nodes, the results of igraph are all 0 while the those of networkx seems to be right. Who can help me with this problem of python-igraph?

Here is the code:

```
from igraph import *
import networkx as nx

print("\tUse python-igraph with Vertices=100 ") 
ig = Graph.Lattice([10, 10], 4, False, False, False) 
bt1 = ig.betweenness(directed=False, cutoff=None,nobigint=False) 
print("\tBetweenness of python-igraph:") 
print(bt1) 
print("\tUse networkx with Vertices=100") 
G_la= nx.grid_2d_graph(10,10,periodic=False) 
bt2 = nx.betweenness_centrality(G_la) 
print("\tBetweenness of networkx:") 
print (bt2)
```

enter image description here  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTeun.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9mAo.png)

Comment: Can you provide the code directly (so that we can copy and paste) rather than in an image?

Comment: Sure，Thanks for your reply. Here are the code of a test on a 10*10 lattice.

Comment: print("\tUse python-igraph with Vertices=100 ")
    ig = Graph.Lattice([10, 10], 4, False, False, False)
    bt1 = ig.betweenness(directed=False, cutoff=None,nobigint=False)
    print("\tBetweenness of python-igraph:")
    print (bt1)

    print("\tUse networkx with Vertices=100")
    G_la= nx.grid_2d_graph(10,10,periodic=False)
    bt2 = nx.betweenness_centrality(G_la)
    print("\tBetweenness of networkx:")
    print (bt2)

Comment: I am sorry. I just do not know how to format these code in a comment. It is my first time to use Stackoverflow.

Comment: You can directly edit your post.  I've just edited it.  Can you check that I did everything right?  In particular, make sure there's nothing wrong with my indenting.  Also, could you edit it and add the import statements?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my reading of the [documentation](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#Lattice) for the igraph Lattice, function, the number `4` you have as its argument means that a node will be connected to any node which is at most 4 steps away on the lattice.  The networkx graph will only connect to the 4 nearest neighbors.  So igraph has a lot more connections.  In the 9-node example, igraph has all nodes connected.

To be clear, networkx would connect the node `(1,1)` with `(1,0)`, `(0,1)`, `(1,2)`, and `(2,1)`, while your igraph command connects it with all of those, but also `(1,3)`, `(1,4)`, `(1,5)`, `(0,4)`, and many others.  (I haven't explicitly checked as igraph isn't on my computer, but I'm fairly certain this is the correct understanding of the documentation).

Comment: Thanks you so much. You are right. I just really misunderstood of the igraph function.It is very kind of you to explain the question for me.